# Wpf Command not firing

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I used already Command Binding in my XAML but strangely this specififc one doesn't work. Did i miss something?

Class for Commands:

```
public class VMCommand : ICommand
{
    public delegate void ICommandOnExecute(object parameter);
    public delegate bool ICommandOnCanExecute(object parameter);

    private ICommandOnExecute _execute;
    private ICommandOnCanExecute _canExecute;

    public VMCommand(Action exec, bool canExec)
    {
        _execute = delegate(object param) { exec(); };
        _canExecute = delegate(object param) { return canExec; };
    }

    public VMCommand(Action<object> exec, bool canExec)
    {
        _execute = delegate(object param) { exec(param); };
        _canExecute = delegate(object param) { return canExec; };
    }

    #region ICommand Members

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute.Invoke(parameter);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute.Invoke(parameter);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Xaml:

```
<ListBox DataContext="{DynamicResource Client}" ItemsSource="{Binding Players}" Background="{StaticResource BrushDark}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="{StaticResource BrushTextNormal}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding KillsZombies}" Foreground="{StaticResource BrushTextNormal}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Score}" Foreground="{StaticResource BrushTextNormal}" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Ping}" Foreground="{StaticResource BrushTextNormal}" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0"/>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.Row="1" Name="Actions" Visibility="Collapsed">
                                        <Button Content="Kick" Style="{StaticResource Button}" Margin="20,5,0,0" Width="50" Height="25" DataContext="{DynamicResource Client}" Command="{Binding Test}"/>
                                        <!--{x:Static local:VMServer+PlayerCommand.KICK}-->
                                        <Button Content="Ban" Style="{StaticResource Button}" Margin="20,5,0,0" Width="50" Height="25" Command="{Binding Test}"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Grid>
                                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" TargetName="Actions"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, Path=IsFocused}" Value="False">
                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" TargetName="Actions"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
```

Whereas in my VM:

```
private VMCommand _test;
    public VMCommand Test
    {
        get
        {
            Action a = new Action(delegate()
            {
                MessageBox.Show("yay");
            });
            return new VMCommand(a, true);
        }
    }
```

In this case Client is my Viemodel here containing all the needed things.

Outside the listbox command binding seems to work like a charm (got a connect button with binding, works perfectly), but the buttons inside the Stackpanel wont fire any event at any time.

Did I miss something?

Comment: Where did you define the Command? What is DataContext="{DynamicResource Client}"?

Comment: You have set the `ItemsSource` for the `ListBox` to be a list of Players, so the `DataContext` for each `ListViewItem` is an instance of Player. 

As per your binding, the Test command should be inside the `Player` class under the property `Client`. 

If you have defined the `Client` property on the main view model, then change your `DataContext` accordingly.

Comment: The hell is ICommandOnExecute? There are plenty of examples of ICommand implementations out there. This one smells.  Go get one that doesn't.

Comment: @AyyappanSubramanian i defined it at top of my xaml `<Window.Resources>
        <local:NegationConverter x:Key="Negation"/>
        <local:VMServer x:Key="Client"/>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="./Resources/Coming Soon.png" x:Key="ComingSoon"/>
    </Window.Resources>`

Comment: @AnandMurali i already tried setting it directly with DataContext at the button, but still didn't fire.

Comment: @Will i second that, but a direct proposal would've been nice

Comment: It would have simply been a copypaste of one of the tens of existing styles of implementation that are already floating around.  It would be better for you to seek them out yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone runs into the same problem that his/her implementation doesn't fire in a particular situation like mine here's my fault:

Setting a event listening on both values true/false prevented my command from being fired.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that following code will solve your problem.
Plesae let me know.

```
<Button Content="Ban" Style="{StaticResource Button}" Margin="20,5,0,0" Width="50" Height="25" Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListBox}, Path=DataContext.Test}"/>
```

Comment: sadly didn't work, i begin to assume maybe my ICommand implementation lacks of something ... :/